# Using django serializer to json while AJAX but using templatetags on response

Tags: django

I have a model table which I am serialized to JSON on an AJAX operation.

Now on the client side I have the model structure as JSON but I would love to use django template tags on the data which has been send.

For example, assume I have a date parameter in my JSON model. django serializer will serialized it and I have no control over it on the client-side because it is already been "compiled".

Is there any way to dosomething like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format the data first, then send a rendered template fragment as your Ajax response, rather than JSON.

Comment: Isn't that breaks the django design ? should I avoid pushing html code to the client ? I guess that it is hidden in a template so thats ok ?

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you can use some javascript based template engine like [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#readme).

```
/* For example */
var json_data = {
    name: "Joe",
    amount: 10.55
};

var template = "{{name}} spends {{amount}}";
$('#some-div').html(Mustache.render(template, json_data));
```

On django templates it is a pain to escape `{{ stuff }}` without something like the very handy `{% verbatim %}` template tag provided by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1313862).

Another approach is: use static files as client side templates and fetch them with AJAX calls.